# how to display database data in to a asp.net table such that data should be displayed in every x seconds

Tags: asp.net

how  to read database data and display in asp.net table in every 'x' seconds.?

If I have 40 records in my database. I need to read data from database and display them in a asp.net table such a way that, 10 records(say) should be displayed in first 6 seconds then the remaining records in next 6 seconds and so on.

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you want a 'display timer' and not everything directly? Have you considered paging instead?

Comment: I am a fresher. i had given a task like this.

Comment: this is what  I have tried...

Comment: i tried asp.net timer control ,but it displays all data at a time in a given interval of time,

Comment: First of all try to refresh your page after x seconds by adding meta refresh. On page maintain one viewstate variable which counts no of records which you have fetched. So next  time you fetch next records.